# Writing python list values to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, selenium

I'm trying to export the list generated to a csv file where each row in the website table corresponds to a new row in the file and each value is in an individual cell, such as:

> NAME.....ICO DATE....ICO PRICE....CURR. PRICE....24 HR ROI
>   Stratis.....06/20/16.......$0.007...........$7.480................+38.80%

The current output looks like this:

> ['Patientory\n05/31/17\n$0.104\n$0.274\n+46.11%\n+25.54%\nN/A']

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

csvrows = []

def get_css_sel(selector):
    posts = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(selector)
    for post in posts:
        print(post.text)
        csvrows.append([post.text])

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Scrapers\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://icostats.com")
wait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#app > div > div.container-0-16 > div.table-0-20 > div.tbody-0-21 > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(8)")))

get_css_sel("#app > div > div.container-0-16 > div.table-0-20 > div.tableheader-0-50")              #fetch header of table
get_css_sel("#app > div > div.container-0-16 > div.table-0-20 > div.tbody-0-21 > div")              #fetch rows of table

def create_csv(thelist):
    with open('ICO.csv', 'w') as myfile:
        for i in thelist:
            wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            wr.writerow([i])

create_csv(csvrows)
```

Answer (score 2):

In `get_css_sel()`, each `post.text` contains the row text separated by newlines `\n` - same as your example of the output. So appending `[post.text]` appends a list with a single item for the full row. Change that to:

```
csvrows.append(post.text.split('\n'))  # remove the extra list brackets
                                       # since split returns a list.
```

Ex:

```
>>> y = 'Patientory\n05/31/17\n$0.104\n$0.274\n+46.11%\n+25.54%\nN/A'
>>> y.split('\n')
['Patientory', '05/31/17', '$0.104', '$0.274', '+46.11%', '+25.54%', 'N/A']
```

Additionally, in your writing loop, you shouldn't re-create the `csv.writer` for every row, just do it once before looping over `thelist`.

And since you have all the rows you want in `csvrows`, you can use [`csvwriter.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) directly.

```
def create_csv(thelist):
    with open('ICO.csv', 'w') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerows(thelist)
```

Comment: That's it! Also, how can I remove the quotes? I can't call remove() on it: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: Which quotes are you trying to remove? In the CSV, you've put `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`. Remove that if you don't want unnecessary quotes. Also, the [default `dialect` is 'excel'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) which is usually sufficient.

Comment: If you're getting empty rows and no text for `post.text` then put `if post.text:` before `csvrows.append...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

csvrows = []
def get_css_sel(selector):
    posts = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(selector)
    for post in posts:
        print(post.text)
        csvrows.append(post.text)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'//Users/Pranavtadepalli/Downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get("https://icostats.com")
wait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#app > div > div.container-0-16 > div.table-0-20 > div.tbody-0-21 > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(8)")))

get_css_sel("#app > div > div.container-0-16 > div.table-0-20 > div.tableheader-0-50")              #fetch header of table
get_css_sel("#app > div > div.container-0-16 > div.table-0-20 > div.tbody-0-21 > div")              #fetch rows of table
new=[",".join(elem.split("\n")) for elem in csvrows]
newfile=open("csvfile.csv",'r')
newfile1=open("csvfile.csv",'w')
newstuff=newfile.read()
for elem in new:
    newfile1.write(elem+'\n')
newfile1.close()
newfile.close()
```